# How to Add Bitbucket as Source code repository to Bluemix tool chanin service

Tags: devops-services

I want to build pipeline in bluemix with bitbucket as my source repository.

I am using Bluemix and by default it takes github as a source code repository.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't. IBM Bluemix only connects to public github repositories in their Continous Integration pipeline.

I suggest to user another solution, like using a tool like Jenkins that can listen easily to changes to the bitbucket repository, and then do the deploy (using the Cloud Foundry CLI) to a Bluemix environment.

Comment: IDK if this is what you want (IBM Cloud docs to configure BB in the toolchain) https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/toolchains_integrations.html#bitbucket.  I'm struggling with what needs to get saved from an IoT node red app.